# Unexpected variable type when testing isolate scope with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I am testing a directive with isolate scope (angular) and Jasmine test framework.  Everything is working fine with one oddity:  if I change the variable type on $scope from string to number, Jasmine continues to see it as a string even though the directive code itself properly treats it as a number.

I understand why this might make intuitive sense - the parm is interpolated initially as a string and maybe Angular has some mechanism for ensuring it stays a string.   If true, I don't get how and where it is implemented in the Angular source (or even how it could be).

***In sum:  Why does Jasmine see a string and the directive see a number?***

Here's my code:

**Markup**

```
<pane id={{myId}}></pane>
```

**Directive**

```
.directive('testPane', function () {

    function thisController($scope) {

       //$scope.id is string '1'
       $scope.id = parseInt($scope.id);

       //now it is number 1 (as expected)
       console.log($scope.id);


    };


    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: { id: '@'},
        controller: thisController,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, tabsController) {


        },
        templateUrl: 'test/test.html',
        replace: true
    };
})
```

**Jasmine Spec**

```
it("changes id from string to number", function () {

    var element,
        elementScope;

    $rootScope.myId = 1;

    element = $compile(html)($rootScope);

    $timeout(function () {
        businessTabScope = element.isolateScope();
        $rootScope.$digest();


        expect(elementScope.id).toBeDefined();

        //id is text '1' instead of number 1. Why?
        expect(elementScope.id).toEqual($rootScope.myId);
    }, 0, false);



   $timeout.flush();


});
```

Comment: This is not an angular issue. When you read data from the dom it comes as string and Angular cannot make assumptions about the type as javascript being a dinamic language

Comment: Not following.   I am reading a property on (isolate) scope.  Inside the directive the type is a number.  From Jasmine it is a string.  Both are looking at the same object - scope.  I don't see how the DOM comes into play.

Comment: Perhaps your controller code (that parses the number to an int) has not yet been executed when you're checking the value in the test? I suspect that's why you're using `$timeout` here... Have you tried adding log statements to see which code is executing? Have you tried increasing the timeout value? By the way, I've never had to use `$timeout` when testing my directives ... I just call `$digest()` on the directive's parent scope.

Comment: the $timeout is there because the directive uses templateUrl.   If that is not added, the call to retreive isolateScope will fail b/c $http hasn't resolved in time.

Comment: @Sunil   I've verified that the controller code executes first.  This can be done by introducing another $scope var defined only within the controller.  The Jasmine code correctly reads it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

When you define an `@` binding, Angular creates an observer for that attribute so it can update the local property's value if that attribute later changes. You can find that particular code at line 7676 ([Angular 1.3.15](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js)):

```
case '@':
  attrs.$observe(attrName, function(value) {
    isolateBindingContext[scopeName] = value;
  });  
  ...
```

Now let's see what [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes#$observe) on `$observe` says about it (emphasis mine):

> Observes an interpolated attribute.
>
> The observer function **will be invoked once during the next $digest
>   following compilation**. The observer is then invoked whenever the
>   interpolated value changes.

So that observer is *guaranteed* to be invoked once after the directive is compiled, that is, after both controller and link functions are executed. And since you are assigning a new value to the `id` property in the controller function, it gets overridden back to its original value - which is a string since it's a DOM attribute.

**Solution**

Given the code you have posted, it seems that you only care about the `id` first value. To grab it you can simply do the following:

```
.directive('testPane', function () {
  return {
    ...
    scope: {},
    controller: function($scope, $attrs) {
      $scope.id = parseInt($attrs.id, '10');
    }
  };
});
```

You can keep using an `@` binding if you want, but make sure the converted value is stored in another property of the scope so it doesn't get overridden - either after the directive is compiled or later on.